# I want to query a many to many relationship that match exactly with the query string array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a post table that has a many to many relationship with a category table, and of course a pivot table between both.

I'm trying to get all posts that match exactly with an array of categories, example:

category_array = [food, travel, people]

So, i want all post that have all those categories inside.

I tried this but didn't work.

```
 $query->when(
            $filters['category'] ?? false,
            function ($query, $category) {
             $query->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($category){
                    $query->whereIn('name', $category);
                    
                });
            }
        );
```

It  just retrieved posts which have one of them.

I expecting only post that have all of the categories. Not just one.

Update I tried this approach, but didn't work as well:

```
  $query->when(
            $filters['category'] ?? false,
            function ($query, $categories) {
                $query->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categories) {
                    foreach ($categories as $cater) {
                        $query->where('name', $cater);
                    }
                });
            }

        );
```

Comment: Is this $category actually equal to mentioned category_arrray?
If that is the case, you should change the condition to:
`$query->whereIn('name', $category);`

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Oh sorry I made a typo writing the question. I used that approach, and I got posts that have some of the categories, but not exactly all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a nested query with a loop on your array to put all your categories in where with `and` like this:

```
function ($query, $category) {
             $query->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use($category){
                    for($categories as $category){
                        $query->where('name', $category);
                    }
                    
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You add an extra condition to whereHas that determine the count of categories relationship have to be equal the count of $categories array

```
$query->when(
    $filters['category'] ?? false,
    function ($query, $categories) {
        $query->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($categories) {
            $query->whereIn('name', $categories);
        }, '=', count($categories));
    }

);
```